# Multiplying small matrices in parallel

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, matrix, pthreads, posix

I have been writing code to multiply matrices in parallel using POSIX threads and I have been seeing great speedup when operating on large matrices; however, as I shrink the size of the matrices the naive sequential O(n^3) matrix multiplication algorithm begins to overtake the performance of the parallel implementation.

Is this normal or does it indicate a poor quality algorithm? Is it simply me noticing the extra overhead of creating and handling threads and that past a certain point that extra time dominates the computation?

Note that this is for homework, so I won't be posting my code as I don't want to breach my University's Academic Integrity Policies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to give an exact answer without seeing the code(or a detailed description of an algorithm, at least), but in general it is normal for simple algorithms to perform better on small inputs because of a smaller constant factor. Moreover, thread creation/context switches are not free so it can take longer to create a thread then to perform some simple computations. So if your algorithm works much faster than a naive one on large inputs, there should be no reasons to worry about it.

Comment: This is what I had thought. Thank you very much!